# Moving a vector "straight out" along a fixed angle

Tags: javascript, vector, html5-canvas, kineticjs, trigonometry

I've searched for the answer to this and have tried many proposed solutions, but none seem to work.  I've been struggling with this forever so any insight is greatly appreciated.

I have 3 shapes (vectors I suppose) on a JS canvas, each with an orientation represented as degrees off of 0 and a width.  I need to drag one of these shapes "straight out" from its orientation.  This is difficult to explain in words so please view the graphic I created:

[image: drag the middle shape straight out]

The middle (diagonal) shape is at 45 degrees.  It's origin is the red dot, (x1,y1).  The user drags the shape and their mouse lies at the green dot, (x2,y2).  Since the shape's origin is in the lower left, I need to position the shape at the position of the lighter blue shape as if the user has dragged straight outward from the shape's origin.

I don't think it matters, but the library I'm using to do this is KineticJS.  Here's the code and some information I have available which may help solve the problem.  This code positions the shape on top of the mouse, which isn't what I want:

```
var rotationDeg = this.model.get("DisplayOri"), // rotation in degrees
    rotationRadians = rotationDeg * Math.PI / 180, // rotation in rads
    unchanged = this.content.getAbsolutePosition(),  // {x,y} of the shape before any dragging

    dragBoundFunc = function (changed) {
        // called on a mouseMove event, so changed is always different and is the x,y of mouse on stage
        var delta = {
            x: changed.x - unchanged.x,
            y: changed.y - unchanged.y
        };

        return changed; // go to the mouse position
    };
```

[edit] I should mention that the obvious of "return delta" doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to constrain the movement of the object.

1. Determine the vector representing the constraint axis : that is, we only want motion to occur along this line. It appears from your drawing that this is in the direction of the short line from the red dot out to the left. That vector has a direction of `-1/m` where `m` is the slope of the line we are moving.
2. Constrain the movement. The movement is represented by the mouse move delta - but we only want the portion of that movement in the direction of the constraint axis. This is done with a `dot product` of the two vectors.

So in pseudo code

```
 m = (line.y2 - line.y1)/(line.x2 - line.x1)
 constraintSlope = -1/m

 contraintVector = {1, constraintSlope}  //unit vector in that direction
 userMove = {x2-x1, y2-y1}               //vector of mouse move direction

 projection = userMove.x * constraintVector.x + userMove.y * constraintVector.y

 translation = projection * constraintVector   //scaled vector
```

Comment: +1 @Mikeb: nice solution!  It fits well with OP's needs because KineticJS allows a custom dragBoundFunc to fit your constraint solution into.

Comment: I can see that this is what I need, but I'm not sure how to get x2,y2 of the line you talk about.  The x2,y2 of that line is the ultimate end point that the blue shape needs to snap to...  In other words, line.x2,line.y2 is the same point I'm trying to find in the original question isn't it?

Comment: The line you are moving has two endpoints - the red dot is near / over one of them, the other is the other end of the dark blue (unmoved) line.

Comment: oh - i misunderstood.  i thought 'line' was the segment connecting the red origin to the destination x,y.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry it took me so long to mark this as the answer - i had moved on to something else!